# gSheets: How to use SPLIT in ARRAYFORMULA over columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

For numbers x and y, I have cell data formatted as x@y.

An example row:

```
| A      |    B   |  C    |  D     |
| ------ | ------ | ----- | ------ |
|10@100  | 10@120 | 8@150 | 5@175  |
```

I want to parse this type of row into two quantities: the sum of the x's and sum of y's.

With my example, I should have two cells:
33 and 545

Basically, I want to SUM the resulting array of SPLIT applied to each cell in A1:D1.

My attempt

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(A1:D1, "@")))
```

Unfortunately, this approach doesn't allow me to specify whether I want x or y (when I call SPLIT) and it seems to be returning x + y, rather than sum(i=1 to 4) x_i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`=index(query(arrayformula(split(transpose(A1:D1), "@")),"select sum(Col1),sum(Col2) ",0),2)`

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you, this worked immediately and easily. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
=ArrayFormula({SUM(INDEX(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(A1:D1),"@"),0,1)),SUM(INDEX(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(A1:D1),"@"),0,2))})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SPLIT(JOIN("@",A1:D1),"@"),ISEVEN(SEQUENCE(1,COUNTA(A1:D1)*2)-1))
```

[image]

```
F3= (replace ISEVEN -> ISODD)
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(A1:D1); "@"); 
 "sum(Col1),sum(Col2)"); "offset 1"; 0))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure if understanding it correctly, but I'm getting a formula parse error. I'm pretty new to gSheets, so please spell it out, if you can.

Comment: @G.J can you share a copy of your sheet?